# Adding a table row object to a PFRelation in Swift with Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfrelation

I'm adding a friendship relation for current user to the row which resembles another user in user table using  table view controller.
I cannot find a way of setting the selected row as a variable, in this instance the object would be called user. The way I currently have throws up an error on the objectAtIndex part.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    var relation : PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("friendship")
    let user:PFObject = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

    relation.addObject(user)
    PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeed:Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Unable to save")
        }
    }

}
```

The error that is thrown underlines `objectAtIndex` and says, "String does not have a member named '`objectAtIndex`'."

I've looked at numerous tutorials and read through lots of documentation and can't find a fix. Any help would be great.
Thanks,
Chris

userArray is defined here..

```
var userArray: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var query = PFUser.query()
        query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
        var users = query.findObjects()
        for user in users {

            userArray.append(user.username)

        }


    }
```

Comment: What type your self.userArray has?

Comment: I'll put that part above..

Comment: One of the issues is that you're putting `String` objects (`user.username`) into `userArray`, but when you try to get them out you're casting them to `PFObjects`. That won't work, and may or may not be related to the `objectAtIndex` issue you're having.

Comment: Okay thanks for getting back to me. I think it is related, as the issue says that objectAtIndex isn't a subset of string. Should I make the array another type?

Comment: If I were you, I'd make the array `[PFUser]`, in `viewDidLoad()` set the array to something like `userArray = users as [PFUser]`, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you'll need to update whatever logic you have to query the `PFUser` for the row rather than assume the array contains a `String`, and then your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should work as is.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have a go now. I'm creating an app for my dissertation and struggling :( Thanks for the help!